# compile vlc android error

Tags: android, compilation, vlc

When I try to compile vlc android project, I got a issue:

```
cd speex-git && patch -fp1) < ../../contrib/src/speex/no-ogg.patch
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 1 (offset -3 lines).
patching file libspeex/Makefile.am
Hunk #1 FAILED at 11.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file libspeex/Makefile.am.rej
patching file src/Makefile.am
Hunk #1 FAILED at 11.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 24.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file src/Makefile.am.rej
make: *** [speex] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

i just solve this problem.
You can download speex-git.tar.gz and put it in contrib/tarballs .
Then sh compile.sh again.