# vlc android compile patching error

Tags: android, compilation, vlc

When I try to compile vlc android project, I got a issue

```
(cd speexdsp-git && patch -fp1) < ../../contrib/src/speexdsp/neon.patch
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 203 with fuzz 1 (offset 35 lines).
patching file libspeexdsp/resample.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 585.

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file libspeexdsp/resample.c.rej
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 98 with fuzz 2 (offset 17 lines).

Hunk #2 succeeded at 166 (offset 26 lines).

Hunk #3 succeeded at 196 with fuzz 1 (offset 30 lines).
patching file libspeexdsp/arch.h
Hunk #1 FAILED at 163.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file libspeexdsp/arch.h.rej
patching file libspeexdsp/fixed_generic.h

Hunk #1 succeeded at 56 with fuzz 2 (offset 4 lines).
```

according to [compile vlc android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451188/compile-vlc-android-error) I have down load speex-git.tar.gz but it dit not work. And https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/11702 offically show the problem, but no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare tow files different between your path vlc/contrib/src/speexdsp/neon.patch and https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/contrib/src/speexdsp/rules.mak.